# AWS EMR Spark - calculate avg of numbers from file on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to calculate avg of numbers given in txt file on S3 with Spark on AWS EMR.

BUt I am not sure what should I use MLib? or sparkSQL? All the references I am seeing are for totally different things. Could anyone guide me in right direction?

```
     SparkConf sparkConf = new 
     SparkConf().setAppName("com.company.app.JavaSparkPi");
     JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    //READING S3 FILE
    //PARSING THE FILE CREATING ARRAY OF NUMBERS

    int slices = 2;
    int n = 10 * slices;
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        l.add(i);
    }

    //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE 
    //SHOULD I USE PARALLELIZE ??
    JavaRDD<Integer> dataSet = jsc.parallelize(l, slices);

    int count = dataSet.map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer integer) {
            //JUST MAP THE INTEGER TO INT?
            //OR SOME LOGIC NEEDS TO BE PLACED
            double x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            double y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            return (x * x + y * y < 1) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }).reduce(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
            //SOME LOGIC HERE?
            return integer + integer2;
        }
    });

    //WRITE S3
    System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n);

    jsc.stop();
```

Comment: Few questions you will have to ask yourself are 1. How do you want to authenticate to S3 bucket. (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/spark_s3.html#spark_s3_credentials) 2. How to get data from S3 into a dataframe (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/spark_s3.html#spark_s3_examples). 3. How comfortable are you with SQL or API (https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/02/statistical-and-mathematical-functions-with-dataframes-in-spark.html)

Comment: @sramalingam24 1) I have ec2 instance profiles setup on cluster that have access to S3 via vpc endpoints. 2) I am unaware of dataframe 3) APIs are better to work with.

Comment: @sramalingam24 I am unsure how to go about it. :( any ref guides you could point  out for aws emr spark?

Comment: `parallelize` is only used if you want to turn some data on the driver into an RDD so you can work on it in parallel.  You instead should be using `spark.read.*` to load in your data in a distributed manner.  Again I would recommend you spend some time reading the spark documents and the things you are trying to do will probably be more clear

Comment: @RyanWidmaier Does that explain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882052/aws-emr-sparkpi-java-running-for-more-than-30-mins? I am running same SparkPi code on cluster mode with class attribute specified to given class

Comment: No, you probably have configuration problems with your driver/executor sizing.  Hard to say though without more information

Comment: I am using terraform to create the cluster. I havent specified any driver/executor sizing on cluster/step no config as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the `Spark SQL`/`DataFrame` functionality.  These APIs provide you SQL like transformations that will give you better performance than the lower level `RDD` APIs.  `MLib` is the machine learning component of Spark, which you don't need to do ETL operations, only if you are training a new ML model.

You should start with some reading.  First, I would start with the general spark documentation.  This will give you an idea how you go about getting data into your Spark job and interacting with it.

[Spark Quick Start](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html)

Then I would read up on EMR.  Specifically on how to create a cluster, and how to access the spark shell:

[Create EMR cluster with Spark](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-launch.html)

[Accessing Spark shell on EMR cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-shell.html)

Once you are in the spark shell, you will be able to load data from S3, the same as you can from HDFS.  For simple text files for example, you could just do (assuming pyspark):

```
df = spark.read.text("s3://some-bucket/path/to/files/")
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I am thorugh with cluster set up. I am not sure what to use? Map-reduce?

Comment: I added sample sparkPi with some qs